# Check if two ed25519 points are equivalent

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519

How to check if two points are equivalent given their projective coordinates (XYTZ)?

For example if I do unproject() of a point to pass from XYTZ to XY coordinates and then I come back to XYTZ coordinates, the new XYTZ coordinates are different respect to the original ones.

How can I be sure that the two points are equivalent in C if they are represented in the following way:

```
struct ed25519_pt {
    uint8_t  x[32];
    uint8_t  y[32];
    uint8_t  t[32];
    uint8_t  z[32];
};
```

Comment: I'll leave the question open for now as there is a language agnostic answer. If you require C code to perform the calculations then you should definitely ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  This is a question about the representation of the point equivalence relation in a particular coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

The affine coordinates are `(X/Z, Y/Z)`.

So, check that `Y1*(1/Z1) ≡ Y2*(1/Z2)` and that the signs of `X1*Z1` and `X2*Z2` are the same.

`Z` being `0` represents the point at infinity.

Slightly longer answer:

Think about `(X, Y, Z)` as a fraction representation of `(X', Y')` with `X' = X/Z` and `Y' = Y/Z`. `T` is just `X*Y` and is not relevant here.

What you mean by "unproject" is going from a fraction to a scalar. Once this is done, you get something equivalent, but the denominator is lost.

You can go back to a fraction representation by setting the denominator to `1`. This is what happens when you go from an affine representation to a projective or extended one.

`(X, Y, Z)` may look different after a round trip, but this is the same set of affine coordinates, just with a different denominator `Z`.

Comment: I presume Z is the denominator? Please do explain that in the answer....